# why is .email:focus { border-color: #1877f2; box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #e7f3ef; } not working?

Tags: html, css, input, border

My HTML and CSS are below; it was working but suddenly it stopped, I tried to remove everything that I coded after this code and it's still not working :(

```css
.email:focus {
  border-color: #1877f2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #e7f3ef;
}

.pass:focus {
  border-color: #1877f2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #e7f3ef;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <input class="email" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email or phone     number" autofocus="1" aria-label="Email or phone number" autocomplete="off" required>
  <input class="pass" type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password" aria-label="password" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
```

I tried to make the input border blue when the cursor is on it, like FaceBook login page, it was working and then stopped.

Comment: The input border *is* blue when focused, though the box-shadow does make it less visible.

Comment: @DavidThomas this seems to be true on Firefox but on my Windows 10 Edge/Chrome it is not blue but black (ie looks like the default browser setting). (seems to be overwritten by outline?)

Comment: @DavidThomas may i ask u what 'OUTLNE' do?

Comment: @DavidThomas i don't think i really know. i have add the border color and the box shadow i thought it will work

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry to bother you with my question, I just did what the engineers said "try to copy famous websits by you'r self"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.email:focus {
  border: 2px solid #1877f2;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #e7f3ef;
}

.pass:focus {
  border: 2px solid #1877f2;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #e7f3ef;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <input class="email" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email or phone     number" autofocus="1" aria-label="Email or phone number" autocomplete="off" required>
  <input class="pass" type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password" aria-label="password" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
```